# How to create an observable that produces a single value and never completes

Tags: c#, sequence, system.reactive, observable

I am aware of `Observable.Never()` as a way to create a sequence that never completes, but is there an extension/clean process for creating an observable that produces a single value and then never completes? Do i go with `Observable.Create(...)`? `Observable.Concat(Observable.Return(onlyValue), Observable.Never<T>())`? Or is there something built in or more "RXy" than this?

Comment: Your `Concat` approach sounds good to me - you could always wrap that up in your own method if you need to use it in multiple places. (It sounds like a relatively rare scenario to me, so I wouldn't particularly expect a built-in method.)

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the feedback. Appreciated, as always.

Comment: Do be careful with observables that never end. It is possible that someone creates a query that holds resources that never get released and hence become a memory leak.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For your specific question, a simple choice is to use ‛Never‛ and ‛StartWith‛:

```
Observable.Never<int>().StartWith(5)
```

But for the more general case of "I have an observable sequence that will produce some results and eventually complete and I want to change it so it does not complete" (of which your question is a special case), your Concat idea is the way to do it

```
source.Concat(Observable.Never<int>());
```

or

```
Observable.Concat(source, Observable.Never<int>());
```

Answer (score 9):

`Observable.Concat(Observable.Return(onlyValue), Observable.Never<T>())` seems to be sound. I was probably overthinking this anyway.

Comment: you can also do `Observable.Never<int>().StartWith(5)`

Comment: @Brandon feel free to leave a full answer, as this is precisely the sort of alternative that I was hoping for. Also, I hate accepting my own answers...feels dirty somehow. :D

Comment: It's not overthinking if there's a chance there may be something 'built-in'

Answer (score 7):

This can be done even simpler use:

```
Observable.Return(whatever);
```

Comment: this would send `whatever` and then immediately complete, which wasn't quite what i was looking for. Thanks for your consideration, though!

Comment: This doesn't exist anymore. This must be what if now `of(...)` ?

Comment: exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Here's a generic utility method to do it in one go. A version of `StartWith` that can be invoked without a source sequence, removing the need for `Never`. Might make your code more readable if you use the construct a lot.

```
public partial class ObservableEx
{
    public static IObservable<TValue> StartWith<TValue>(TValue value)
    {
        return Observable.Create<TValue>(o =>
        {
            o.OnNext(value);
            return Disposable.Empty;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here's the Create version:

```
Observable.Create<int>(subj => {
    // Anyone who subscribes immediately gets a constant value
    subj.OnNext(4);

    // We don't have to clean anything up on Unsubscribe
    // or dispose a source subscription
    return Disposable.Empty;
});
```

Comment: I'd rename `subj` to `ob` or `o` to reflect that it's an observer rather than a subject.