# Observable of IDisposable object: How to dispose previous value onNext and onComplete?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I have an `Observable` of `IDisposable` value

```
IObservable<IDisposable> disposableValues = source.Select(val => MyDisposableObject());
```

How to write a pipe that dispose old value, when:

1. new value is emitted
2. when the source completes?

I think #1 can be achieved with `Buffer`, however how do I access last value on `onComplete` callbak?

```
disposableValues
    .Buffer(2)
    .Do(buffer => buffer[0].Dispose())
    .Finally(_ => { ??})
    .Subscribe();
```

Maybe I'm doing it wrong and I could use `CancellationToken` or something...

Comment: It really seems like you're doing something wrong here. It's odd to have a `IObservable<IDisposable>`. Can you please give us a bit more context as to what this observable is meant to do? Obviously you're not just creating disposable objects and disposing them without using them in some way.

Comment: Related: [Dispose of Observable Items as they are generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50669745/dispose-of-observable-items-as-they-are-generated)

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in the comment, I think it is a bit odd to have a `IObservable<IDisposable>`. It's hard to reason about the lifetime of the disposable in an observable pipeline like this.

What is more likely is that you have an observable that needs to use a disposable object that you **want to do something with** and you want to ensure it is disposed afterwards.

Let's assume you have this disposable:

```
public class MyDisposableObject : IDisposable
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething!");
    }
    
    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dispose!");
            }
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
}
```

It has something to do and it let's us know when it disposes.

Now for the query.

```
var source = new Subject<Unit>();

IObservable<Unit> observable =
    source
        .SelectMany(u =>
            Observable.Using(
                () => new MyDisposableObject(),
                mdo => Observable.Start(() => mdo.DoSomething())));
        
observable.Subscribe();
```

It uses the `Observable.Using` operator to create the disposable and then is able to start an observable that uses the disposable. As soon as it completes or if the `source` observable completes everything gets disposed.

Try this test code:

```
source.OnNext(Unit.Default);
source.OnNext(Unit.Default);
source.OnNext(Unit.Default);
source.OnCompleted();
```

That gives me:

```
DoSomething!
Dispose!
DoSomething!
DoSomething!
Dispose!
Dispose!
```

Everything is nicely disposed and a clean observable is created with no side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Buffer()` is the right way to get the "previous" object, but you should use `Buffer(2,1)` to get a "sliding window". Then you start your subscription with a default value (like `null`) AND let it end with a default value (also `null`). The goal is to get a sequence like this:

```
[null, obj1]
[obj1, obj2]
[obj2, obj3]
[obj3, null]
```

You will have four events and for three of them you can call `Dispose()`.
For the first `null` you can use `StartWith(null)` which precedes your actual data. For the last `null` you use `Concat()` to add a [observable with only one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443398/how-to-create-an-observable-that-produces-a-single-value-and-never-completes) by using `Observable.Never()` and `StartWith()`. When your original observable completes you will get a "fake" event where you can dispose your last used object. Check the following example:

```
public class Program
{
    public class TestObject : IDisposable
    {
        public TestObject(int value) {
            this.Value = value;
        }

        public int Value { get; }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Dispose called for {this.Value}");
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"TestObject({this.Value})";
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {   
        using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
        {
            ISubject<TestObject> source = new Subject<TestObject>();
            IDisposable subscription = source
                .StartWith((TestObject)null)
                .Concat(Observable.Never<TestObject>().StartWith((TestObject)null))
                .Buffer(2,1)
                .Subscribe(it => {
                    Console.WriteLine("Array content: "+String.Join(", ", it));
                    TestObject first = it.First();
                    TestObject last = it.Last();
                    if (first != null) {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Found an old object {first}, dispose it");
                        first.Dispose();
                    } else {
                        Console.WriteLine("There is no previous object");
                    }

                    if (last != null) {
                        Console.WriteLine($"'Current' object is: {last}");
                    } else {
                        Console.WriteLine("No 'current' object");
                    }
                });
            source.OnNext(new TestObject(1));
            source.OnNext(new TestObject(2));
            source.OnNext(new TestObject(3));
            source.OnCompleted();
            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        }
    }
}
```

This will generate the following debug output:

```
Array content: , TestObject(1)
There is no previous object
'Current' object is: TestObject(1)
Array content: TestObject(1), TestObject(2)
Found an old object TestObject(1), dispose it
Dispose called for 1
'Current' object is: TestObject(2)
Array content: TestObject(2), TestObject(3)
Found an old object TestObject(2), dispose it
Dispose called for 2
'Current' object is: TestObject(3)
Array content: TestObject(3), 
Found an old object TestObject(3), dispose it
Dispose called for 3
No 'current' object
Finished
```

Comment: I actually don't need to start with null, since I can't dispose null. Instead of concat I could use Append(null), right? It makes it somewhat more readable

Comment: @Liero When you don't start with `null`, you will not see the `[null, obj1]` event/data. This means that you might not react on the first object properly but start with the second object from the source instead. Didn't know of the existence of `Append()`, but it looks like it is doing the same (but much simpler).

Comment: Why do I need `[null, obj1]`, when there is `if(first! =null) `?

Comment: @Liero When you don't have the `[null, obj1]` event, you might "miss" the first entry as the sequence would start with `[obj1, obj2]` and you might look at the second argument only. This assumes you have some real payload to do with the current object from the original source. When this specific subscription is only used to dispose disposables and not doing anything with the "current" entry, then it might work to skip the first `[null, obj1]` entry.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is something similar with the [`Do`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html) operator, but for the previous element. Below is an implementation of a custom `DoOnPrevious` operator:

```
/// <summary>Invokes an action for the previous element in the observable
/// sequence. The action for the last element is invoked when the observable
/// sequence completes.</summary>
private static IObservable<T> DoOnPrevious<T>(this IObservable<T> source,
    Action<T> onPrevious)
{
    return source
        .Select(x => (Item: x, HasValue: true))
        .Append((default, false))
        .Scan((previous, current) =>
        {
            if (previous.HasValue) onPrevious(previous.Item);
            return current;
        })
        .Where(entry => entry.HasValue)
        .Select(entry => entry.Item);
}
```

Usage example:

```
disposableValues
    .DoOnPrevious(x => x.Dispose())
    .Subscribe();
```